# How to disable keyboard appearing on mobile : React date time picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [React-date-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker) for my Reactjs App.When i tested date picker option on mobile,keyboard also appearing.
i tried some this.but it is not solve my issue.

```
<DatePicker  onChange={this.bidHandleChangeStart} 
value={this.state.startDate} name="startDate" maxDate={new Date()}  customInput={<CustomInput />} />

const CustomInput = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {
    return (
        <input
            readOnly={true}
        />
    )
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem using the `keyboard` module.

**Example**

```js
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';
...
  componentDidMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      this._keyboardDidShow,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow() {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
    Keyboard.dismiss()
  }
```

Comment: It's ReactJs Application.not a React-native app.I want to hide keyboard on Mobile web browser.so i can't import from `react-native`.right?

Comment: @YasiruAttanayake Why did you add React-native as a tek? Are you developing it as a React?

Comment: Yes.It's ReactJs Application

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the blur when receiving focus. I don't know React but something like:-

```
onFocus={this.blur()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past and fixed by @Oleg.

Here is an example. I think it's helpful to you.

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

...
<Input caretHidden onFocus={(e) => Keyboard.dismiss()} />
...
```